# star rating using ajaxcontroltoolkit not working

Tags: c#, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, rating-system, user-feedback

Here is my code in which star rating is not working.

```css
.filledRatingStar {
  background-image: url('C:\Users\chhaya.kaushik\documents\visual studio
 2015\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Images\filled star.jpg');

}

.ratingStar {
  font-size: 0pt;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.emptyRatingStar {
  background-image: url('C:\Users\chhaya.kaushik\documents\visual studio
 2015\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Images\star-empty.png');
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Modal Example</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button --><button type="button" class="btn
    btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Feedback
    Form</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">MAY WE ASK YOU SOMETHING</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>
                Rating (5: Excellent 4: Very Good 3: Average 2: Poor 1: Very Poor)
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                    <ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="Rating1" runat="server" MaxRating="5" CurrentRating="1" CssClass="ratingStar" StarCssClass="ratingItem" WaitingStarCssClass="Saved" FilledStarCssClass="Filled" EmptyStarCssClass="Empty" AutoPostBack="True" OnChanged="Rating1_Changed"></ajaxToolkit:Rating>
                  </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

                Select Issue :
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
                  <asp:ListItem Text="Response time"></asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Text="Security"></asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Text="Network issue"></asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Text="Interactivity"></asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Text="Look & Feel"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>

                Do you have suggestions on what we can do to provide you with a better service?

                <textarea id="comment" cols="20" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Please leave your
    issues,suggestions or compliments here."></textarea>

              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" Text="Submit" data-dismiss="modal" />
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Any exceptions, etc...?

Comment: no exception...the checkboxlist, the textarea everything is visible in the modal popup except the 5 stars that I want to display for rating. I am using 2 images 1 for filled star and other for empty star

Comment: your image url is wrong

Comment: use: `Images\star-empty.png` and `Images\filled-star.png`